# Mediaplayer action buttons next,previous, repeat and shuffle

Tags: java, android, service, android-mediaplayer, onclicklistener

For some reason, the repeat and shuffle buttons are not doing anything.

The buttons previous and next work perfectly.

In my app I am communicating with my service through broadcasts.

`mediaPlayer` is a public static in my service class and I am importing it in other activity.

`public static MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();`    (In Service.class)

**Activity**

**This is the code for the buttons**

```
if (mediaPlayer != null) {
        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mBtnPlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_pause_white);
            tvSongListSize.setText((songIndex + 1) + "/" + songList.size());
            updateProgressBar();
        }
    }

    mBtnShuffle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (isShuffle){
                isShuffle = false;
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Shuffle is off", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
                mBtnShuffle.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_shuffle);
            }else{
                isShuffle = true;
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Shuffle is on", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                mBtnShuffle.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_shuffle_on);
                isRepeat = false;
                mBtnRepeat.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_repeat);
            }
        }
    });

    mBtnRepeat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (isRepeat){
                isRepeat = false;
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Repeat is off", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                mBtnRepeat.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_repeat);
            }else{
                isRepeat = true;
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Repeat is on", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                mBtnRepeat.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_repeat_on);
                isShuffle = false;
                mBtnShuffle.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_shuffle);
            }
        }
    });


    mBtnPlayPause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                        mediaPlayer.pause();
                        mBtnPlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_play);
                    } else {
                        mediaPlayer.start();
                        mBtnPlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_pause_white);
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    mBtnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            nextSong();
        }
    });

    mBtnPrev.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            prevSong();
        }
    });
```

**Code in onCompletionListener**

```
@Override
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
    if (isRepeat){
        //Store current songIndex in mSharedPreferences
        StorageUtil storageUtil = new StorageUtil(getContext());
        storageUtil.storeSongIndex(songIndex);

        //Send media with BroadcastReceiver
        Intent broadCastReceiverIntent = new Intent(Constants.ACTIONS.BROADCAST_PlAY_NEW_SONG);
        if (getActivity() != null) {
            getActivity().sendBroadcast(broadCastReceiverIntent);
        }
    }else if(isShuffle){
        Random random = new Random();
        songIndex  = random.nextInt((songList.size() - 1) + 1);
        tvSongListSize.setText((songIndex + 1) + "/" + songList.size());

        //Store random songIndex in mSharedPreferences
        StorageUtil storageUtil = new StorageUtil(getContext());
        storageUtil.storeSongIndex(songIndex);

        //Send media with BroadcastReceiver
        Intent broadCastReceiverIntent = new Intent(Constants.ACTIONS.BROADCAST_PlAY_NEW_SONG);
        if (getActivity() != null) {
            getActivity().sendBroadcast(broadCastReceiverIntent);
        }
    }else if (songIndex < songList.size()-1){
        mediaPlayer.reset();
        nextSong();
        tvSongListSize.setText((songIndex + 1) + "/" + songList.size());
    }else{
        songIndex = 0;
        tvSongListSize.setText((1) + "/" + songList.size());

        //Store random songIndex in mSharedPreferences
        StorageUtil storageUtil = new StorageUtil(getContext());
        storageUtil.storeSongIndex(songIndex);

        //Send media with BroadcastReceiver
        Intent broadCastReceiverIntent = new Intent(Constants.ACTIONS.BROADCAST_PlAY_NEW_SONG);
        if (getActivity() != null) {
            getActivity().sendBroadcast(broadCastReceiverIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

**Broadcast receiver**

```
 private BroadcastReceiver NewSongBroadCastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        songList = new StorageUtil(getApplicationContext()).getSongs();
        songIndex = new StorageUtil(getApplicationContext()).loadSongIndex();
        if (songIndex != -1 && songIndex < songList.size()){
            activeSong = songList.get(songIndex);
        }else{
            stopSelf();
        }
        stopSong();
        mediaPlayer.reset();
        if (mMediaSessionManager == null) {
            try {
                initMediaSession();
                initMediaPlayer();
            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                stopSelf();
            }
        }
        initMediaPlayer();
        updateMetaData();
        NotificationBuilder(PlaybackStatus.PLAYING);
    }
};
```

Comment: You mean you don't even see the toasts?

Comment: @mTak Yes i can see the toasts, but oncompletion doesn't work

Comment: @mTak any idea why it doesn't work?

Comment: See my answer__

Answer (score 0):

The buttons `mBtnShuffle` and `mBtnRepeat` do not trigger `onCompletion`.  They are just 2 ordinary buttons that you use to set the flags isShuffle and isRepeat. 
`onCompletion` is triggered **when a song has been completed**.  
So if you want something to happen when the 2 buttons are tapped you should put some code in their listeners.

Comment: but in the oncompletion listener im checking if those flags are true or not, isn't it supposed to work?

Comment: Yes but after the song has finished not the moment you press the button

Comment: right, so i want that to check if for example the button repeat is active, if it's active i want that when the song is over -> the song repeats so why doesn't it work in oncompletion

Comment: because when i put the code in the listener it immediately repeats the song, but i want it to repeat when the song is over.

Comment: So leave it as it is for the repeat button. If isRepeat is true it will execute the code in onCompletion.

Comment: well that's my problem, it doesn't do anything when the song is over :')

Comment: Did you debug the code in `onCompletion`? Is `isRepeat` true? What is `Constants.ACTIONS.BROADCAST_PlAY_NEW_SONG`?

Comment: an intent filter in my service class which starts a new song

Comment: But if you want the same song when isRepeat is true why do you start a new song?

Comment: naming is a bit off, but the broadcast receiver just loads my songs and position from sharedpreferences, so when i broadcast Constants.ACTIONS.BROADCAST_PlAY_NEW_SONG it replaces old song and position

Comment: So maybe storing and retrieving from sharedpreferences is wrong

Comment: yeah i found the problem, i was storing the wrong sondIndex -_-

Comment: Anyway if you solved it it's ok, but the problem would be solved easier if you phrased the question more appropriately.

Comment: yeah sorry about that, but problem is still there, weird thing is that is works perfectly in an activity, but not in a fragment. I have a fragment with at the bottom a slidinguppanel but for some reason it doesn't work.

Comment: Ok nvm, i just made those flags public static and imported them in my service and in there oncompletion works perfectly. sorry about the vague post but i really appreciate the help.

Comment: Ok_____________